# Phantom MEASURE value in Table

Tags: graph, measure, switching, phantom-reference

I have a Measure called [SelectedDate].

```
SelectedDate = IF(SELECTEDVALUE(OrdersByCalendar_DTL[OrderDate] )=Blank();Blank();SELECTEDVALUE ( OrdersByCalendar_DTL[OrderDate]))
```

I am attempting to use it to make a graph displaying Month totals disappear when a date is selected from a slicer...PowerBI-101.

```
MonthCol1 = IF([SelectedDate]="Blank"; OrdersByCalendar_DTL[CNT Date(SUM) per Period]; Blank())
```

It worked until I switched the slicer to another slicer and now the measure seems to be returning PHANTOM values which is causing my IF([SelectedDate]=Blank();sum(Column1);Blank()) to ALWAYS return a value.

I only found this out (after pulling out half my hair) by switching the graph to a table and adding a CARD that displays the [SelectedDate] value.  Low and behold, [SelectedDate] is populated with values in the table whilst the CARD clearly shows [SelectedDate] to be (Blank).  Another strange fact is that while each date's MonthCol1 value is Blank() (as per the measure), the Total at the bottom is the correct tally for the month.

[Screenshot of Measure taking on phantom values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wl77.png)

Any ideas?

I've tried adding the measure to the graph's filter section and selecting IS BLANK...The graph now shows absolutely nothing even when selecting a date.  This is due to (I believe) the [SelectedDate] measure taking on un-authorized date values as shown in the screen shot.